# When moving a subview around, how do I keep a subview of it in the same place in its superview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

That's a very convoluted title. Sorry.

Basically, I have a `UIView` that I've attached to a `UITableViewCell` so I can slide the cell around, or at least create the tric-- illusion of it. Within that `UIView` I have a `UIImageView`. I want to keep this `UIImageView` static relative to the *view controller*. So basically when I slide the cell around, I want everything about the cell to slide around with my finger (I have this done) EXCEPT the `UIImageView`. I want it to seem to the user like it's staying in one place -- which means to the cell's superview (the view controller's view) it's staying in one place.

What would be the easiest way to build this? I'm sorry I don't have code to share, I'm just trying to build this from a conceptual level first. My `UIView` on the `UITableViewCell` is slid with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and moving the `UIView`'s frame if that helps.

Would I have to move it in the opposite direction of the `UIView` when it moves (say it moves one forward in x, move it one back in x?) or is there a way where I can just say "lock your position relative to your super-superview"?

Comment: You need to move it in the opposite direction. It shouldn't be that hard, since you already have implemented the UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Comment: so did my answer below work out for you? please lemme know, also what library are you using to implement this slider feature? or did you do it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

abood was close, but close, but if you simply make the imageview a subview of the cell itself instead of the UIView I added over the cell, they operate independently. So contrary to the first line, adding it as a subview of UITableViewCell worked perfectly and didn't have any of the issues outlined. Works perfectly now.

Comment: ugh man! if i was close then at least give me an upvote! lool

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem before.. what I did was simply not add the `UIImageView` as a subview to the `UITableViewCell`, and instead attach it to the parent of the `UITableViewCell`.. that way whatever happens to the `UITableViewCell` frame properties (ie size or origin) won't impact your `UIImageView`..

you may wonder: well one of the reasons I attach the UIImageView as a subview to the tableCell is b/c it's related to it in many different ways.. The response to that is that you can associate an object with another through `objc_setAssociatedObject`

If you come from web dev background, you can think of this discussion as the difference between `position:absolute` and `position:relative` discussion.

Initially I tried to do what you had in mind, basically moving them in opposite directions etc.. I just think my solution is a lot simpler to do.

Comment: It sounds like a good idea, but being a table view cell, don't you still want the image to move up and down with the scrolling of the table? Maybe you can have the gesture recognizer move contentView and the image be a direct child of the table view cell (sister of contentView).

Comment: @morningstar sure you are right.. i'm not sure about the exact arrangement (i would have to test around a bit with which view i'd attach the UIImageView to) but the idea is to decouple the UIImage view from the UITableView somehow..